# Dynamic div height - other dynamic div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

So I'm trying to create a box which is the same height as the entire page, (live height) - another dynamic div named `#wrapping`, so I have this piece of code which offsets it instead of removing the height of the div...

```
function jsUpdateSize() {
  var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
  $('#box').height(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset().top);
}
window.onload = jsUpdateSize; // When the page first loads
window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;
```

So I want it to take away `#wrapping`'s height from it's own, sorry if this a really easy question :)

Comment: Man, I'm re-reading this question several times, and I just can't understand what you mean by *take away #wrapping 's height from it's own*

Comment: @LcSalazar *I meant the box, sorry for any confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
function jsUpdateSize(){
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    var wrappingHeight = $('#wrapping').height();
    var offset =  wrappingHeight - viewPortHeight ;
    $('#box').height(wrappingHeight - offset);

}
$(document).ready(jsUpdateSize); //on page load
$(window).resize(jsUpdateSize);  //when the window is resized
```

Comment: Fixed it, by the way; the wrapping div isn't wrapping the box... It's wrapping my title, but I fixed it using your solution thank you :)

Comment: Ah ok yeah i was just guessing at your HTML but the jQuery you can just adjust. No problem

Comment: Thanks, but, I have to vertically center something in this #box; but I also need to be able to scroll down to the next page, any help?

Comment: Do you need to have the box scroll also or just have it centered within the page but set in the same place?

Comment: It needs to scroll because I'm doing a single-page website, any help?

Comment: That would probably be easiest with CSS